# Shouldn't my Belkin USB hub be able to power on a USB MIDI keyboard?

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I have a Belkin 2-in-1 USB hub.

[image]

This is a powered USB hub.

Therefore I would believe it to be able to power on my AKAI MPK Mini keyboard.
However, the keyboard doesn't power on.

The USB hub has the power light on, which means that it ought to be powered (from the wall socket).
Other things that work is that I can plug my Galaxy S3 to the hub and it will start charging. However, it doesn't seem to mount.

Is this a power issue or a driver issue (i.e. that the keyboard should be connected directly to the computer, rather than through a hub)?

There are no other hubs between this hub and my PC's USB port (from which the keyboard powers on).

---

This question could also be in some other SE, but I think in order to understand the problem on a technical level, this is the appropriate SE. Another idea might be to contact AKAI or Belkin directly.

Comment: What is the power requirements on the MIDI keyboard?  What are the power specs on the USB hub?   If you connect the keyboard directly to the USB port on the computer, does it work?

Comment: What the heck is "a Belkin 2-in-1" hub? What-in-what? You have a specific problem, why you are not specific about the subject?

Comment: Do you have any more hubs in your system before the Belkin  hub?

Comment: Does any other USB device (mouse, pen drive) work in the secondary hub?

Comment: It is a powered hub, but all of the power available to the ports in the silver plug-in expansion unit appears to come from that unit's connection.  If you are using all of its ports, you might be exceeding the power available to the expansion unit.

Comment: I re-phrase the question, does any other NORMAL simple USB device work in this hub? Also, is there any difference between bottom (base) ports, and ports on upper attachment?

Answer (score 0):

Your [manual](http://6be54c364949b623a3c0-4409a68c214f3a9eeca8d0265e9266c0.r0.cf2.rackcdn.com/461/documents/mpk_mini___quickstart_guide___reva___english_00.pdf) (Page 6) says the keyboard is powered by USB and draws only 100 mA.
This should be well within range of any powered USB hub.

If your keyboard works when plugged into the computer USB ports and does not work plugged into the Hub, I'd suspect the USB Hub power supply. Virtually all USB hubs will source power from their uplink port when required (so you could leave the power supply unplugged and things will work), but it might impact the 5V supply fed to the keyboard. If the keyboard is sensitive to a drop in 5V this might be your problem.

Comment: The keyboard specs list the actual power consumption. However, we don't know if the USB descriptor part of this device holds the same information, and does not report something like "102" mA (by programmer's mistake or misunderstanding the format of descriptor field). However, in this case Windows should pop a warning message. The OP also does not tell if there is any difference in behavior of bottom (base) ports, or in secondary (upper plug-in unit) ports. Nor he failed to test the hub with ANY normal USB device to see if it works at all.